# How to change the value based getting value in Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have taken the values from database using Entity Framework , I have that a class called `EmployeeDetail` in that I have  one property called `JOined AS`.

It gives the values as 'F' for fresher and 'E' for experience.. I need to display this value in
DataGrid as Experience or Fresher instead of F or E..

For that I have created the partial class for `EmployeeDetail` and created one property `CustJoinedAs` ...

But I didn't get idea to compare the value and return the required value to DataGrid Column...

Here I also have to give each value to DataGrid.. is it automatically bind when I give the property to Column in DataGrid...or any propetyChanged Events have to be Write..

please give a brief idea.. and Code..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the property in partial class like

```
public partial class EmployeeDetail
{
    public string CustJoinedAs
    {
       get{return this.JoinedAs = "E"? "Experienced" : "Fresh";}
    }
}
```

And bind column of grid to CustJonedAs despite of JoinedAs.